Make GNOME recognize WM_NAME and WM_ICON_NAME
I'm launching Battle.net with https://usebottles.com/, and it creates two windows: one for the launcher itself, and one for the game. Both windows are missing an icon and show "steam_proton" mouseover tooltip.

I know I can control appearance of application menu items with StartupWMClass property, but both these windows have the same WM_CLASS of steam_proton, so I can't do that. What's different for these windows, is WM_NAME and WM_ICON_NAME properties, but GNOME seems to ignore those. Is there any way I can make GNOME use them?
